# Can I SSH into my pi via a USB-to-USB connection with my laptop?

Tags: networking, usb, ssh, ethernet, putty

My laptop does not have a built-in ethernet port because it is new so I used to SSH with my pi via a USB-ethernet adapter but I recently went to Russia and forgot the adapter in the US and since I am in Russia, nobody sells such adapters and when I did find one, it was a fake Apple adapter made by ASIX which was cheap but did not work due to driver errors.

My only option now it seems is to use a USB-USB cable for connecting to my pi and I just want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. There's no protocol to connect computers by usb. But there are a lot options to connect PI by wifi (for example making access point by your Mac).

Edit: Now i see "putty" tag. So i think that youre not using Mac. Despite it you can still connect Pi and your PC by connecting to the same wifi net (for example your phone hotspot)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but the solution is even older.  Male to Male USB bridge networking cables. See the article(from 2005) for a better explanation.  Amazon has plenty of similar, if not the same, cables available at the time of this writing(12/2018). While it's not the exact solution to the question I thought I'd add this so future users can be made aware.

[image: USB to USB bridge cable]

**Connecting Two PCs Using a USB-USB Cable**(November 16, 2005):
https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/connecting-two-pcs-using-a-usb-usb-cable/